# Does an apache cordova app works as signalR Client without any issue?

Tags: cordova, signalr, visual-studio-cordova

does anyone has the experience of implementing signalR client in apache cordova app in a live product. Is it possible? and Is there any buggy issue that occures on specific platform?

Comment: Yes it is possible to use SignalR within an Apache Cordova app

Comment: Thanks @KiwiPiet, did you do it any application , I searched for it but did not get any official walkthrough in msdn ...

Comment: Cordova is essentially JavaScript and HTML, so whatever you can do on a website you can do in Cordova

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you ca use SignalR with an Apache Cordova project (as @KiwiPiet points out in the comments). Here are some posts online that discuss getting it working. Some of these posts mention PhoneGap which should also apply here. PhoneGap is built on top of the open source Apache Cordova project.

http://agilefromthegroundup.blogspot.com/2012/09/getting-signalr-and-phonegap-working.html

MyShuttle is a set of sample apps, and it includes a Cordova app that communicates via SignalR:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cesardelatorre/archive/2014/12/01/myshuttle-biz-and-multi-device-development-of-hybrid-apps-for-ios-android-and-windows-with-visual-studio-tools-for-apache-cordova.aspx

Comment: Thanks @Jordan Matthiesen